# yahoo oauth $user->getProfile(); returns null

Tags: php, yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm using php and downloaded the yahoo library to import yahoo user info.

I've already finished it and it has been working flawlessly, but now it has started to return:

> Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object
>   [APP/Vendor/Yahoo/Yahoo.inc, line 1036]

This notice appears after logging in through yahoo. When I debug `$user->getProfile()` it returns null.

I didn't change anything in my code that's why i don't have any idea what is causing it.

Please help!

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'YahooInc', array('file' => 'Yahoo/Yahoo.inc'));
$session = YahooSession::requireSession($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$app_id);
if (is_object($session)) {
    $yahooUser = $session->getSessionedUser();
    $yahooProfile = $yahooUser->getProfile();
}
```

Comment: show some of your code, that would help

Comment: Have you got a solution to this? I'm having the same issue, it returns null, if you've got it, do you mind sharing it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to replace your current Yahoo Api library with the below github branch.

```
https://github.com/syamvilakudy/yos-social-php
```