# Not able to fetch contacts from yahoo api

Tags: yahoo-api

I've included yahoo API to read user's yahoo contacts. However it's not fetching any data.
Please have a look at my code:

```
session_start();
include_once 'config.php'; //This file contains consumer key & all data
require_once ('Yahoo.inc'); //This is a standard Yahoo file, just copied it
$session = YahooSession::requireSession($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$app_id);
if (is_object($session))
{
    $user = $session->getSessionedUser(); //This is NOT NULL
    $profile = $user->getProfile(); //This is NULL
    $name = $profile->givenNme;
    $guid = $profile->guid;
    $contacts=$user->getContacts()->contacts; //This is NULL
    if($contacts==NULL){
        echo "No contacts";
    }
}
```

Somehow `getProfile()` & `getContacts()` are not working at all, anyone can help spot the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this thread: [yahoo oauth $user->getProfile(); returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371336/yahoo-oauth-user-getprofile-returns-null). It solves the problem. You need to switch over to the new API. Otherwise, you may experience this kind of problems.